Change a variable from a number of randomly-selected GameObject clones
I'm trying to replicate Minesweeper.
I have this code that spawns a bunch of squares in a grid formation to make the game board; this leaves me with 100 game objects all named "square(clone)"
//10x10 grid
yPos = yStart;
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{   
    xPos = xStart;
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++)
    {
        newPos = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
        Instantiate(coolsquare, newPos, Quaternion.identity);
        xPos = xPos + 1f;
    }
    yPos = yPos - 1f;
}

The squares have this script with a few working IDs that tell me their row and column, and also a status bool
public bool marked = false;
public int rowid, columnid;

filacolum = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tablerofacil").GetComponent<tablerofacil>();
rowid = filacolum.row;
columnid = filacolum.column;

I want to be able to select a random set of these squares and change their status to "marked = true".
I tried a few things like tags with GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("square").GetComponent<squarecode>(); but I can't find a way to access to the variables of multiple clones. in fact, I can't find a way to change the variables value of any other clone other than the first.

FindGameObjectWithTag("TagSpecificToComponentWeWant").GetComponent<ComponentWeWant>() is an unnecessarily complicated way to write FindAnyObjectByType<ComponentWeWant>(). This shorter version is significantly faster, and saves you from having to use up tags to do the same job of identifying the object's type/capabilities that the component already does on its own. Note too that type names like classes should generally start with an uppercase letter, and saying they're "code" isn't especially informative since all your code is code. So instead of squarecode I'd call this a GridCell.

Another easy approach if you need to load a specific element and do not want to store it for whatever reason when you instantiate it, after you instantiate one element, you can rename it to include the position in it's name.

@Zibelas that could be posted as an answer, I'd say, with an example of how to look up a specific position by name.

My approach would be to have the spawner-script retain the references to the squares it spawned and store them in a two-dimensional array. You can then use that array to quickly access a square by its index.
A two-dimensional 10x10 array looks like this:
public GameObject[,] squares = new GameObject[10,10];

I am declaring it public here, so other scripts might access it through a reference to the spawner. It might be cleaner to make it private and hide it behind an accessor method. Or probably the spawner might not be the best place to store that array and it might make more sense to put it into a dedicated "Squares" class that might or might not be accessible from other scripts via the Singleton pattern. But these are architectural intricacies with no right or wrong solution. You have to decide what's the best solution for your particular game.
But once you have your array, you fill it like this:
squares[row, column] = Instantiate(coolsquare, newPos, Quaternion.identity);

If you want to access the square in the 4th row and 5th column, you access it like this:
GameObject square = squares[3, 4];

(remember that arrays start at 0).

Since they ultimately want to change a variable on the squarecode class, it may be helpful to make the prefab variable of type squarecode and the array squarecode[,] so the correct type is returned directly from Instantiate and array indexing, without a need to call GetComponent. Though I would also advise them to improve their nomenclature to something like GridCell or such.
